# What is the song playing in "Kore wa Zombie Desu ka?" ep. 11 at 11:24?

Tags: music, kore-wa-zombie-desu-ka

In *Kore wa Zombie Desu ka?* season 1 episode 11, there's a song playing at 11:24 and ends at roughly 12:26 ([YouTube video by Funimation](https://youtu.be/mhdAPS3Fb70?t=11m24s), region-locked for North America).

What is the name of the song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The song playing is OST piece 19 called "Yami no chikara"

This song were included in the the second released OST set with specials by **Shinji Kakijima** whom composed all the songs through out the [kore-wa-zombie-desu-ka](/questions/tagged/kore-wa-zombie-desu-ka) series